# Python Discord bot send text upon exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a function in my Discord bot that acts as a magic 8 ball where you ask it a question and gives a random reply. An exception occurs when the function is called but no question is asked, and I would like to get an error message of some kind print to the channel it was called in notifying the user that this error as occurred. Here's what I attempted:

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball', 'eightball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *,question):
    responses = ['yes', 'no', 'maybe so']
    response = random.choice(responses)
    try:
        await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\n\
        Answer: {response}')
    except MissingRequiredArgument:
        await ctx.send("Please ask a question")
        pass
```

But nothing prints out except in the terminal.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument) and "replace me" in str(error):
        await ctx.send("You're missing a required argument idiot.¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
```

With discord.py you can't really use a try and except. You'll need to check with an on_command_error event. Replace the `"replace me"` with whatever comes out after your MissingRequiredArgument error. For example `MissingRequiredArgument: arg is a required argument that is missing.`
Then you'll replace `"replace me"` with `"arg is a required argument that is missing"`

Btw, next time when you receive errors in your code, please add them to your question. It helps us understand what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help! And I'm assuming that this is the same idea for other errors as well? And does this mean that this is the event that will handle all other `MissingRequiredArgument` going forward

Comment: Yes, it is the same for the other errors. As for the handling of multiple MissingRequiredArguments, that depends on the message in the str(error). Just make sure the argument names are different so that errors will be different.